# Grails change default home page to spring security core login screen

Tags: grails

I installed the Grails Spring Security Core plugin. As it works right now, a user is first taken to the default index.gsp page which lists the controllers. Once they click on a controller, they are prompted to log-in.

How can I modify Grails to show the log-in screen first, and re-direct to the default index.gsp page upon success?

Here is my Config.groovy:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.example.app.security.SecUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.example.app.security.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.example.app.security.SecRole'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
'/attendance/*':        ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/class/*':             ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/county/*':            ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/person/*':            ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/state/*':             ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/**':                  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

UrlMappings.groovy:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ constraints { // apply constraints here
        } }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')

    "/login/$action?"(controller: "login")
    "/logout/$action?"(controller: "logout")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
'/': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
```

to your interceptUrlMap.

Then, when a visitor goes to "/", spring security will intercept and redirect to the login page, then redirect to "/" after the login.

Comment: Hi GreyBeardedGeek, I tried that before (and just tried again), and the log-in screen still doesn't come up (I did make sure that I was logged out of previous sessions and that I cleared my cache). I posted  a copy of my UrlMappings.groovy, does everything look OK there?

Comment: Alas, I did not restart the server (I thought the change would be picked up and applied). Once I restarted the server, it worked. Thanks!